# Pause MediaBrowserServiceCompat audio using OneTimeWorkRequest

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-workmanager, android-mediasession

I need to pause the audio playback in my app after a certain amount of time.  I'm using a `OneTimeWorkRequest`:

```
OneTimeWorkRequest sleepTimerWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(SleepTimer.class)
        .setInitialDelay(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build();

WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(sleepTimerWorkRequest);
```

I am using a `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` class to play the audio but I'm not sure how to pause the audio from the `Worker` class.  I tried doing something like this but it doesn't work:

```
public class SleepTimer extends Worker {

    private static WeakReference<Context> mContext;

    public SleepTimer(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
        mContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {

        MediaSessionCompat mediaSessionCompat = new MediaSessionCompat(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class.getSimpleName());
        mediaSessionCompat.getController().getTransportControls().pause();

        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would say you're using the wrong too for the job. WorkManager is for deferrable work, not exact time. You want something exact timed (nothing that might be deferred for minutes or hours).

Comment: What would you recommend for a sleep timer function?

Comment: I ended up switching to a foreground service and using a CountDownTimer instead of the OneTimeWorkRequest.